# how to bucket empty and non empty fields in nested aggregation in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have the following set of nested subaggregations in elasticsearch (field2 is a subaggregation of field1 and field3 is a subaggregation of field2).
It turns out however that the terms aggregation for field3 will not bucket documents that dont have field3.

My understanding is that I have to use a Missing subaggregation query to bucket those in addition to the term query for field3.

But I am not sure how can I add it to the query below to bucket both.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "f1": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "field1",
        "size": 0,
        "order": {
          "_count": "asc"
        },
        "include": [
          "123"
        ]
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "field2": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "f2",
            "size": 0,
            "order": {
              "_count": "asc"
            },
            "include": [
              "tr"
            ]
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "field3": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "f3",
                "order": {
                  "_count": "asc"
                },
                "size": 0
              },
              "aggregations": {
                "aggTopHits": {
                  "top_hits": {
                    "size": 1
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74022715/elasticsearch-query-nested-array-for-empty-and-specific-value-in-single-query

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In version 2.1.2 and later, you can use the [`missing` parameter of the terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_missing_value_12), which allows you to specify a default value for documents that are missing that field. (FYI, the `missing` parameter was available starting 2.0, but [there was a bug](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/14882) which prevented it from working on sub-aggregations, which is how you would use it here.)

```
     ...
     "aggregations": {
        "field3": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "f3",
            "order": {
              "_count": "asc"
            },
            "size": 0,
            "missing": "n/a"     <----- provide a default here
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "aggTopHits": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 1
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

However, if you are working with a pre-2.x ES cluster, you can use the [`missing` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/search-aggregations-bucket-missing-aggregation.html) at the same depth as your `field3` aggregation to bucket the documents that are missing "f3" like this:

```
     ...
     "aggregations": {
        "field3": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "f3",
            "order": {
              "_count": "asc"
            },
            "size": 0
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "aggTopHits": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 1
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "missing_field3": {
          "missing" : {
            "field": "f3"
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "aggTopMissingHit": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 1
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: I am on version 2.1.1 but unfortunately the newer way doesnt work on an inner level see this issue https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/14882

Comment: Good call. I was testing on a 2.2 cluster and it worked as expected. I was not aware of the bug in 2.1.1 and prior. I have updated my answer to clarify in which version the `missing` option works and included the link you provided to the bug details.